# DIVS se deslocam conforme o tamanho do navegador

Tags: css, navegador-de-internet

As **divs** se deslocam conforme o tamanho do navegador muda.
[image]

Quando eu mudo o tamanho do navegador.
[image]

```css
body
{
 margin: 0; 
 background: #FFF;
}

/*CLASSES UTEIS*/
.foco:focus
{
 outline: none;
}

/*CABEÇARIO*/
#cabecario
{
 width: auto;
 height: 40px;
 background: #7bdac1;
}
#logo_div
{
 float: left;
 width: 141px;
 height: 40px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 position: relative;
}
#logo
{
 margin-top: 3px;
}
#search_div
{
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 height: 40px;
 margin-left: 70px;
 position: relative;
}
#search_bar
{
 width: 300px;
 height: 26px;
 margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>LuppBox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div id="cabecario" name="cabecario">
   <div id="logo_div" name="logo_div">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBNwP.jpg" id="logo" name="logo" width="auto" height="35">
   </div>
   <div id="search_div" name="search_div">
    <input id="search_bar" name="search_bar" type="search" class="foco">
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um exemplo do problema que possa ser reproduzido.

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta o HTML e o CSS que estou usando.

Comment: Lucas eles não podem ser reproduzidos como na imagem, por favor poste um exemplo do problema que possa ser reproduzido, ajude-nos a ajuda-lo. Grato

Comment: Arrumei, pode ser executado agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
#cabecario
    {
        width: auto;
        height: 40px;
        background: #7bdac1;
    }
```

Coloque uma largura específica ao invés de automático, tipo:

```
width: 1000px;
```

Atualização:

Coloque dessa forma que você vai entender:

```
#cabecario
        {
            min-width: 600px;
            height: 40px;
            background: #7bdac1;
        }
```

Dessa forma quando reduzir o tamanho do navegador ele não vai deixar as divs se deslocarem, porque você definiu um tamanho mínimo. Ele vai sempre exibir as divs no tamanho necessário para não distorcer.

Coloquei 600px no exemplo, mas você pode testar valores menores, como 500px e ver até aonde não vai deslocar as divs.

Comment: Como devo proceder para pegar o tamanho da tela de quem esta acessando ??

Comment: Você precisa que apareça em 100%, certo? Defina um tamanho mínimo então. Verifique em qual largura as divs se deslocam e coloque esse como sendo o mínimo da largura: min-width: 600px por exemplo.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo executável em sua resposta ??

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Verifique e me fale

Comment: Funcionou bem, vlw.